# Convert an international phone number into a national number

Tags: java, phone-number, libphonenumber

I'm using the [`libphonenumber`](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) google library to convert an international phone number into a national number.

```
var phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
var phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(internationalPhoneNumber, null);
var formattedPhoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL).replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

An example of an `internationalPhoneNumber` is "+919744012345"

The `formattedPhoneNumber` I am expecting is "9744012345" ([See the Mobile telephone numbering in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India)), but instead, I am getting "**0**9744012345" with a leading zero.

How to convert the international phone number correctly?

Comment: In most countries, a leading "0" is part of the national phone number. Guess, the library you are using, does exactly so.

Comment: "In written phone numbers, it is not uncommon to see the area code preceded by a '0'. The '0' is India's national direct dialing (NDD) code used for making domestic long distance calls. If your are making an inbound international call and have a number starting with '0', you'll need to remove it." - the international number does not have the 0 (between the +91 and 97), your local number has a leading 0, so it seems ok to me. But you could also remove the leading 0 from a national India number, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you must set the correct number format.
Have a look to `PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat:`
INTERNATIONAL and NATIONAL formats are consistent with the definition in ITU-T Recommendation E123.

Detailed information is in the [Javadoc of class PhoneNumberUtil](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.4.1/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html)

Answer (score 1):

In many countries you should write the 0 before the phone number , i think that the library will give you the correct format used in the given country.

If your choice is to delete the first 0 for all the phone numbers you can just replace the first 0 with a blank "" :

```
var phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
var phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(internationalPhoneNumber, null);
var formattedPhoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.format(phoneNumber, NATIONAL).replaceAll("\\s", "");
if(formattedPhoneNumber.startsWith("0"))
         formattedPhoneNumber=formattedPhoneNumber.substring(1);
```